# compilation error with the build.py script in Kivy

Tags: android, python, kivy

I have recently installed a Ubuntu 13.10 virtual machine and have set the Kivy development environment for it i.e cloning kivy, building a distribution with distribute.sh and building an apk with the build.py script. While packaging my project to APK file and while running the ./build.py script i had the following error :

```
[aidl] /home/administrator/sdk/build-tools/19.0.1/aidl: error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

BUILD FAILED
/home/administrator/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:653: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/administrator/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:659: null returned: 127

Total time: 1 second
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./build.py", line 412, in <module>
    make_package(args)
  File "./build.py", line 336, in make_package
    subprocess.check_call([ANT, arg])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 540, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['ant', 'debug']' returned non-zero exit status 1 re
```

it is really confusing! I have downloaded SDK and NDK and pointed to where these files are located while setting my environmental variables. what am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well i have solved it in the end! And the clue was here

```
[aidl] /home/administrator/sdk/build-tools/19.0.1/aidl: error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Explained : the Linux distro that i am working on is on a 64 bit machine so some c++ libraries were necessary to be able to run 32 bit applications so what i did is the following:

```
$ sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6
```

and it was solved!

Comment: I also needed to install `lib32z1`.